# How to show created ToolTipControl from ToolTip Component?

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, tooltip, popupwindow

I have created a simple control which acts as a ToolTip and i have implemented drawing the text and painting the background in the control as my wish. No issues in this control side.

and also i have developed a component for ToolTip which integrates the created ToolTip with the controls. here is the component class.

```
[ProvideProperty("ToolTip", typeof(Control))]
public class ToolTipController : Component, IExtenderProvider
{
    public ToolTipController()
    {

    }




    Dictionary<Component, ToolTip> toolTipInfo = new Dictionary<Component, ToolTip>();

    Dictionary<Component, ToolTip> ToolTipInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return toolTipInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            toolTipInfo = value;
        }
    }


    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        if (!(extendee is ToolTipController))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides value for the Extended property Tooltip for controls.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Value of the extended property.</returns>
    public ToolTip GetToolTip(Component component)
    {
        if (ToolTipInfo.ContainsKey(component))
            return toolTipInfo[component];
        return null;
    }

    public void SetToolTip(Control control, ToolTip toolTip)
    {
        if (toolTip == null)
            return;
        if (!ToolTipInfo.ContainsKey(control))
        {
            ToolTipInfo.Add(control, toolTip);

            toolTip.AddControl(control);
        }
        else
            toolTipInfo[control] = toolTip;
    }



}
```

Here is the Control for ToolTip.

```
public class ToolTip : Control
{
    #region Private Variables
    RightToLeft rightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
    Dictionary<IntPtr, Component> components;
    TOOLINFO toolInfo;
    Color foreColor;
    Color backColor;
    private string tipText;
    Dictionary<ContentAlignment, TextFormatFlags> formatFlags;
    #endregion Private variables


    public ToolTip()
    {

        toolInfo = new TOOLINFO();
        components = new Dictionary<IntPtr, Component>();



        formatFlags = new Dictionary<ContentAlignment, TextFormatFlags>();
        formatFlags[ContentAlignment.TopLeft] = TextFormatFlags.Default;
        formatFlags[ContentAlignment.TopCenter] = TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
        formatFlags[ContentAlignment.TopRight] = TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Right;
        formatFlags[ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft] = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left;
        formatFlags[ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter] = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
        formatFlags[ContentAlignment.MiddleRight] = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Right;
        formatFlags[ContentAlignment.BottomLeft] = TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.Left;
        formatFlags[ContentAlignment.BottomCenter] = TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
        formatFlags[ContentAlignment.BottomRight] = TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.Right;
    }


    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the RightToLeft value of the ToolTip.
    /// </summary>
    public RightToLeft RightToLeft
    {
        get
        {
            return rightToLeft;
        }
        set
        {
            rightToLeft = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Text to be drawn in the ToolTip.
    /// </summary>
    public string TipText
    {
        get
        {
            return tipText;
        }
        set
        {
            tipText = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ForeColor of the ToolTip.
    /// </summary>
    public Color ForeColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (foreColor == null)
                return base.ForeColor;
            return foreColor;
        }
        set
        {
            foreColor = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the BackColor of the ToolTip.
    /// </summary>
    public Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (backColor == null)
                return base.BackColor;
            return backColor;
        }
        set
        {
            backColor = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion Properties

    internal void AddControl(Component component)
    {
        if (component != null)
        {
            if (component is Control)
            {
                Control control = component as Control;

                control.HandleCreated += new EventHandler(Control_HandleCreated);
                control.HandleDestroyed += new EventHandler(Control_HandleDestroyed);

                if (control.IsHandleCreated)
                {
                    Control_HandleCreated(control, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    void Control_HandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    public const int TTF_IDISHWND = 0x0001;
    public const int TTF_SUBCLASS = 0x0010;
    public const int TTF_TRANSPARENT = 0x0100;

    public const int LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACKW = -1;

    private TOOLINFO GetTOOLINFO(Control ctl)
    {
        TOOLINFO toolinfo = new TOOLINFO();
        toolinfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TOOLINFO));
        toolinfo.hwnd = this.Handle;
        toolinfo.uFlags = TTF_TRANSPARENT | TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_IDISHWND;
        toolinfo.uId = ctl.Handle;
        toolinfo.lpszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACKW;
        return toolinfo;
    }

    void Control_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;
        if (control != null)
        {
            components[control.Handle] = control;
            toolInfo = this.GetTOOLINFO(control);


            NativeTip.SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), 1074, 0, ref toolInfo);
        }
    }

    #region Overrides
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);

        int style = NativeTip.GetWindowLong(this.Handle, (int)SetWindowLongOffsets.GWL_STYLE);
        NativeTip.SetWindowLong(this.Handle, (int)SetWindowLongOffsets.GWL_STYLE, style & ~(int)WindowStyles.WS_BORDER);

    }


    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.ClipRectangle, Color.Red, Color.Black, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);

        TextFormatFlags textFormatFlags = TXTFORMAT.COMMON;
        textFormatFlags |= TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft;


        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.TipText, this.Font, e.ClipRectangle, this.ForeColor, textFormatFlags);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.ClipRectangle);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

    }

    #endregion Overrides

}
```

I have integrated the ToolTip with below code,

```
ToolTipController controller = new ToolTipController();

ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.TipText = "My test tip";

controller.SetToolTip(this.button1, toolTip);
```

But the created tooltip is not associated with the button.

Does anyone know how to show the created ToolTip control while hovering in other controls?

Regards,
Amal Raj

Answer (score -1):

Heres a snippet from one of my programs, add a mouse hover event and inside add this, you can also make tooltips for controls that dont have them.

```
ToolTip dockItem = new ToolTip();
dockItem.SetToolTip(this.pictureBox1, Path.GetFileName(DeskDocker.Properties.Settings.Default.DockItem1));
```

Comment: I am not asking for using default MSToolTip. I have developed my Custom ToolTip control, here i need to integrate it with the other controls.