# How to set Custom control as ToolTip for Button or Label?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tooltip, custom-controls

I have created a custom control of my own and i am in a need of making this custom control as a ToolTip for the Labels or Buttons.

But i could not find a way to set the Custom control as ToolTip.

Anyone please help me on setting the Custom control as ToolTip.

**Note:**
I don't need solution with showing the Custom Control in mouse_hover events of controls.

Please suggest me ideas to make the custom control as default ToolTip in standard way.

Regards,

Amal Raj

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already know about overriding the paint event, so I won't go into that. If you want anything a bit more complicated, deriving from the `ToolTip` control to extend it for your purposes won't make much sense since you'll run into restrictions quite fast.

What you should do is implement your own ToolTip control by reusing some important bits from the original one. If you're feeling adventurous you could follow these steps to get started. I'm going to refer to your custom control as *tooltip* from now on:

1. If you want to show custom text or something else for each control that uses your tooltip, you need to implement [IExtenderProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356395(v=vs.110).aspx) in your class. [Here's](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/4683/getting-to-know-iextenderprovider) more about it.
2. You need to keep track of controls that are using your tooltip and the custom values you've set for them. Internally, Windows Forms tooltip uses a [HashTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx) for that purpose. Key is the control showing your tooltip and value is the tooltip text (or something else you want to tie to your tooltip).
3. If you want to have more than just one string to show (title, description, image etc), you can have multiple HashTables.
4. When adding the tooltip to a control, subscribe to mouse events (enter, move, leave) to keep track of when to show the tooltip. If you want to have a delay before showing the control, you need to use an internal timer to keep track of time.
5. You'll most likely want the tooltip to extend outside the main form's boundaries. You could wrap your tooltip inside a headerless form or an [alpha blended form](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20758/Alpha-Blended-Windows-Forms) to allow other shapes than rectangle.

Those are the very generalized first steps. In reality, there's quite a bit more to be done. It's been a few years since I implemented my custom ToolTip control so I might be forgetting something crucial. However, if you spend some time poking around the code of [Windows Forms's ToolTip](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolTip.cs) class, you'll get quite a good idea of what's going on behind the curtains.

I haven't reviewed the code myself but judging from the ratings, this article will give you a good starting point too: [A ToolTip with Title, Multiline Contents, and Image](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98967/A-ToolTip-with-Title-Multiline-Contents-and-Image). It's in VB.NET but you can easily convert it to C# by using [Telerik's converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) or any other.

Comment: I have created a control as fresh, not derived from ToolTip. And i have created a Controller class with ExtenderProvider for ToolTip. Normally, the control for ToolTip and the control added for ToolTip will be configured through SendMessage. But SendMessage return 0 as failure for my implementation. Do you know any possibility for this failure?

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626873/how-to-show-created-tooltipcontrol-from-tooltip-component for my code implementation

Comment: @Amal Oh, looks like you were already quite far with the implementation! I'll take a look when I get to my Windows computer.